# how to eliminate text delimiter in excel using java

Tags: java, json, csv, apache-poi, split

My csv file contains pipe delimiter and the data will look like below in csv,

```
ID| Name|   details
 1|   xx|     {
                "user":"xx",
                 "email":"xxx@xxx.in"
         }
```

If i edit the csv in notepad, the value is displayed as,

```
 1|xx|"{
""user"":""z"",
""email"":""e""
}"|"
```

In my program, i am splitting the values based on pipe delimiter. The problem is that when i get the value of details from csv, it is having extra delimiter (") appended to the each values which is causing my program to fail.

Can anyone provide a solution to eliminate the extra delimiter and get only the exact value i provided in csv?

Comment: My program will get the values from the csv file based on the ID and one of the column will have json value. If i am doing things more complex in my program, is there any other simple approach for this? thanks in advance

Comment: No, I just wondered about the line breaks. But if they can't be avoided in the Excel file, you'll have to deal with them here.

Comment: Why are you trying to write your own CSV reader? There are a number of excellent CSV libraries out there, use one of those!

Comment: Hi gagravarr.. I tried opencsv and other libraries. I am facing the problem when i use json in my csv data. Is there any way to handle json? Please give a sample program, that would be helpful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a line:

```
line.replaceAll( "\"", "" );
```

Which works only if you don't have any quotes in your data. OTherwise, it'll be more complicated - parsing.

(Of course, I'm referring to the snippet we've seen earlier, when line reading didn't finish with the line containing the closing '}'.)

If you want to keep one quote,

```
line.replaceAll( "\"\"", "\"" );
```

I'm not sure about the trailing `}"|"` - why isn't this in the first data sample? You can, of course, simply discard the last 3 characters using substring.

If you check for the last line in a group by doing:

```
if( inline.endsWith( "}\"|\"" ) ){
    inline = "}\"";
}
```

and now these three characters are gone, and you know that group is finished. Then, remove other quotes, or replace double quotes by a single quote.

The third field will also be enclosed in quotes. You can remove these by using

```
String[] cells = line.split( "|" );
cells[2] = cells[2].substring( 1, cells[2].length()-2 );

// and now double quotes to single quotes
cells[2] = cells[2].replaceAll( "\"\"", "\"" );
```

Comment: Yes.. The problem is that when i check for the closing '}' in while loop, it is returned null pointer exception because the value is added with extra delimiter ("). So the while loop is not ended after reaching '}'. How to skip the extra delimiter in while looo?

Comment: Does it make sense now? All together: read lines, detect the end of the group while joining partial lines, split composed line (according to '|'), remove (in 3rd cell) outer quotes and then convert all double quotes to a single quote.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick solution. i will try it now

Comment: It worked :) I also made lot to regex to replace the special characters for parsing the Json

Comment: Good. Another one closed ;-)

Comment: :) laune, i am new to json and i am facing lot of problems when getting the value from csv based on id and assign the values in every column to its corresponding variable. Json is having comma in its syntax, so i am not able to split the values based on comma and save it in a map. I need to replace the comma in json with another string and save it in map. This look like complex when parsing the json from CSV. Is there any easy approach to achieve this?

Comment: IIRC, I've seen some SW that splits on comma irrespective of the data containing commas. After the split, chunks are investigated for unbalanced quotes, and joined accordingly ("ab, cd"; "ab,cd,ef"; etc.) Search the web - I hardly ever use Excel.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html This should be good.